# Steroids error: "Your Node.js version is outdated" while using newest node version

Tags: node.js, cordova, yeoman, steroids

I am trying to install steroids. Steroids depends on node version 0.10, but when I try to install it with node 0.10.38 (currently the most recent version of 0.10) it returns me an error, that my node is outdated.

Why does it tell me that my node version is outdated, when I am using the most recent version of 0.10?

```
    $ node -v
    v0.10.38

    $ npm -v
    2.11.3

    $ npm install steroids
    /
    > steroids@4.1.9 preinstall /home/jl/node_modules/steroids
    > node ./bin/preinstall.js || nodejs ./bin/preinstall.js




    AppGyver Steroids² 4.1.9 installation

    If you have any problems, please visit our forums at http://forums.appgyver.com
    We are now trying to detect required dependencies and problems.
    Some dependencies (like dtrace-provider) will print ugly warnings to the screen, but everything should be fine.

      - The AppGyver team (contact@appgyver.com)


    Starting installation in ...
    3
    2
    1
    Lift-off!


    Checking for compatibility with Node.js version v0.10.38 ... OK

    Checking for required components ...

      Found gcc, good.
      Found make, good.
      Found git, good.

    Dependencies ... OK

    Checking $HOME/.npm ownership, making sure that 'jl' owns everything ... OK
    Checking $HOME/.npm write acess, making sure that 'jl' has write access ... OK

    Dependencies and permissions looks good! Starting Steroids installation...

    npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency yo@>=1.0.0 included from generator-steroids will no
    npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
    npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
    npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.6
    npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
    npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
    npm ERR! registry error parsing json

    > spawn-sync@1.0.11 postinstall /home/ml/node_modules/steroids/node_modules/yo/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync
    > node postinstall

    -
    > yo@1.4.7 postinstall /home/ml/node_modules/steroids/node_modules/yo
    > yodoctor


    Yeoman Doctor
    Running sanity checks on your system

    ✔ Global configuration file is valid
    ✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
    ✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
    ✖ Node.js version

    Your Node.js version is outdate.
    Upgrade to the latest version: https://nodejs.org

    ✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
    ✖ npm version

    Your npm version is outdated.

    Upgrade to the latest version by running:
    npm install -g npm


    Found potential issues on your machine :(
    steroids@4.1.9 node_modules/steroids
    ├── express-json@1.0.0
    ├── colorize@0.1.0
    ├── path-extra@0.3.0
    ├── open@0.0.4
    ├── chrome-cli@1.5.0-AppGyver-p0
    ├── chalk@0.3.0 (ansi-styles@0.2.0, has-color@0.1.7)
    ├── data.either@1.2.0
    ├── wrench@1.5.4
    ├── q@0.9.7
    ├── oauth@0.9.10
    ├── qrcode-terminal@0.9.4
    ├── semver@2.3.1
    ├── ios-sim@3.1.1-AppGyver-p1
    ├── portscanner@1.0.0 (async@0.1.15)
    ├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
    ├── coffee-script@1.6.3
    ├── bluebird@2.3.5
    ├── winston@0.9.0 (cycle@1.0.3, stack-trace@0.0.9, eyes@0.1.8, isstream@0.1.2, pkginfo@0.3.0, async@0.9.2, colors@1.0.3)
    ├── tiny-lr@0.1.4-AppGyver-p0 (parseurl@1.3.0, qs@2.2.5, debug@2.0.0, faye-websocket@0.7.3)
    ├── xml2js@0.4.4 (sax@0.6.1)
    ├── lodash@2.4.1
    ├── restler@3.2.2 (qs@0.6.6, yaml@0.2.3, iconv-lite@0.2.11, xml2js@0.4.0)
    ├── request@2.53.0 (caseless@0.9.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.6.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, node-uuid@1.4.3, qs@2.3.3, combined-stream@0.0.7, form-data@0.2.0, mime-types@2.0.14, http-signature@0.10.1, bl@0.9.4, tough-cookie@2.0.0, hawk@2.3.1)
    ├── fs-extra@0.13.0 (jsonfile@2.1.1, ncp@1.0.1, rimraf@2.4.0)
    ├── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.6, winston@0.6.2, utile@0.2.1)
    ├── js-yaml@3.0.2 (argparse@0.1.16, esprima@1.0.4)
    ├── body-parser@1.8.1 (media-typer@0.3.0, raw-body@1.3.0, bytes@1.0.0, depd@0.4.4, qs@2.2.3, iconv-lite@0.4.4, type-is@1.5.7, on-finished@2.1.0)
    ├── express@4.8.8 (merge-descriptors@0.0.2, utils-merge@1.0.0, cookie@0.1.2, escape-html@1.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0.4, finalhandler@0.1.0, fresh@0.2.2, range-parser@1.0.0, vary@0.1.0, media-typer@0.2.0, serve-static@1.5.4, methods@1.1.0, parseurl@1.3.0, buffer-crc32@0.2.3, path-to-regexp@0.1.3, depd@0.4.4, qs@2.2.2, debug@1.0.4, type-is@1.3.2, proxy-addr@1.0.1, accepts@1.0.7, send@0.8.5)
    ├── chokidar@1.0.0-rc3 (async-each@0.1.6, is-binary-path@1.0.1, glob-parent@1.2.0, readdirp@1.3.0, anymatch@1.3.0)
    ├── inquirer@0.3.4 (mute-stream@0.0.3, async@0.2.10, lodash@1.2.1, cli-color@0.2.3)
    ├── grunt@0.4.5 (dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3, which@1.0.9, eventemitter2@0.4.14, getobject@0.1.0, rimraf@2.2.8, colors@0.6.2, hooker@0.2.3, async@0.1.22, grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0, exit@0.1.2, nopt@1.0.10, minimatch@0.2.14, glob@3.1.21, lodash@0.9.2, coffee-script@1.3.3, underscore.string@2.2.1, iconv-lite@0.2.11, findup-sync@0.1.3, grunt-legacy-log@0.1.2, js-yaml@2.0.5)
    ├── xmlbuilder@2.6.1 (lodash@3.3.1)
    ├── figlet@1.1.0
    ├── steroids-android-packages@0.0.9
    ├── bower@1.3.8 (is-root@0.1.0, junk@0.3.0, stringify-object@0.2.1, chmodr@0.1.1, which@1.0.9, abbrev@1.0.7, opn@0.1.2, archy@0.0.2, rimraf@2.2.8, bower-logger@0.2.2, graceful-fs@3.0.8, bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2, lockfile@0.4.3, lru-cache@2.5.2, nopt@3.0.2, retry@0.6.1, tmp@0.0.23, q@1.0.1, chalk@0.4.0, osenv@0.1.2, bower-config@0.5.2, request-progress@0.3.1, shell-quote@1.4.3, bower-json@0.4.0, p-throttler@0.0.1, mkdirp@0.5.1, fstream@0.1.31, promptly@0.2.1, fstream-ignore@0.0.10, tar@0.1.20, decompress-zip@0.0.8, request@2.36.0, bower-registry-client@0.2.4, cardinal@0.4.4, insight@0.3.1, mout@0.9.1, handlebars@1.3.0, update-notifier@0.2.2, glob@4.0.6, inquirer@0.5.1)
    ├── npm@2.1.7
    ├── steroids-connect@1.0.33
    ├── steroids-ios-packages@4.0.3
    ├── yeoman-generator@0.17.7 (dargs@2.1.0, isbinaryfile@2.0.4, rimraf@2.4.0, class-extend@0.1.1, diff@1.4.0, text-table@0.2.0, mime@1.3.4, underscore.string@2.4.0, debug@1.0.4, async@0.9.2, chalk@0.5.1, grouped-queue@0.3.0, cross-spawn@0.2.9, nopt@3.0.2, run-async@0.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, iconv-lite@0.4.10, mkdirp@0.5.1, file-utils@0.2.2, glob@4.5.3, github-username@1.1.1, findup-sync@0.1.3, download@1.0.7, cheerio@0.17.0, gruntfile-editor@0.2.0, inquirer@0.7.3)
    ├── yo@1.4.7 (titleize@1.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.2, figures@1.3.5, user-home@1.1.1, opn@1.0.2, humanize-string@1.0.1, string-length@1.0.0, sort-on@1.2.2, yeoman-character@1.0.1, repeating@1.1.3, findup@0.1.5, configstore@1.1.0, root-check@1.0.0, meow@3.3.0, chalk@1.0.0, async@1.2.1, yosay@1.0.4, package-json@1.2.0, insight@0.6.0, got@3.2.0, update-notifier@0.5.0, npm-keyword@1.1.1, fullname@1.1.0, yeoman-environment@1.2.5, lodash@3.9.3, yeoman-doctor@1.4.0, cross-spawn@0.4.1, inquirer@0.8.5)
    └── generator-steroids@1.0.19 (mustache@0.8.2, chalk@0.5.1, yosay@0.3.0, coffee-script@1.8.0, underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash-node@2.4.1)
```

Steroids explicitly doesn't support node 0.12

```
    $ nvm use 0.12
    Now using node v0.12.4 (npm v2.10.1)
    $ npm install steroids
    \
    > steroids@4.1.9 preinstall /home/jl/P/node_modules/steroids
    > node ./bin/preinstall.js || nodejs ./bin/preinstall.js




    AppGyver Steroids² 4.1.9 installation

    If you have any problems, please visit our forums at http://forums.appgyver.com
    We are now trying to detect required dependencies and problems.
    Some dependencies (like dtrace-provider) will print ugly warnings to the screen, but everything should be fine.

      - The AppGyver team (contact@appgyver.com)


    Starting installation in ...
    3
    2
    1
    Lift-off!


    Checking for compatibility with Node.js version v0.12.4 ...
      __________________  ___________
    _/ __ \_  __ \_  __ \/  _ \_  __ \
    \  ___/|  | \/|  | \(  <_> )  | \/
     \___  >__|   |__|   \____/|__|
         \/

    In version 3.5.11, Steroids was updated to work on Node.js version 0.10.x only. You are currently using Node.js v0.12.4.

    If you have NVM installed, you can use the '$ nvm install 0.10' command to install Node.js 0.10.x, and '$ nvm alias default 0.10' to make it your default Node.js version.

    See the installation instructions at https://academy.appgyver.com/installwizard for more information.

    NOTE: After you have updated your Node.js version (check with '$ node -v'), you need to write '$ npm install steroids -g' (instead of 'npm update') to update Steroids npm.


    Do you really want to ignore these words of wisdom and continue anyway? (y/N)
```

Comment: Yeoman is [recommending you upgrade to Node 0.12.x](https://github.com/yeoman/doctor/blob/981a38601e7575e6c04d92d718c51528cc4ec233/lib/rules/node-version.js#L5). Steroids should be compatible with 0.12 as well. It just [lists 0.10 as a minimum](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/blob/v4.1.9/package.json#L55).

Comment: Steroids explicitly doesn't support 0.12 and advices strongly to install 0.10

Answer (score 1):

Most recent version of node is currently v0.12.4. This is Yeoman recommending you upgrading to 0.12, not steroids.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Unfortunately it doesn't make it easier to install steroids. So yeoman asks me to install a node version that doesn't support steroids, so I can install steroids? Did I understand it right?

Comment: There is no reason steroids would not work with 0.12, is there ?

Comment: Steroids depends on "node": ">=0.10.17", and 0.12.4 >= 0.10.17, so this will work.

Comment: I've added the steroids response when using 0.12. Steroids explicitly doesn't support it and advices strongly against using it

Comment: "In version 3.5.11, Steroids was updated to work on Node.js version 0.10.x only. You are currently using Node.js v0.12.4." Current version of Steroids is 4.1.9. I guess Node v0.12 did not even exist at time of Steroids 3.5.11, so this advice does not realy makes sense.

Comment: DId you have any real problem at running steroids with node 0.12 ?